# Tests fail with has_paper_trail

Tags: rspec, paper-trail-gem

I have an app with two models - **news** and **audio**.

Having added paper_trail to the project, and putting has_paper_trail in both the models, the app works correctly, but some tests for the news model fail.

News items have a method that check the body for a valid audio URL, and then looks that up (Audio.find) based on the ID in the URL. It is this, and similar methods that call other models, that fail.

If I remove has_paper_trail from the audio spec, the news tests all pass. The audio tests all pass with or without.

PaperTrail is disabled for tests (and I have a test to check that is the case).

What is causing the news test that call a method on another model to fail, but work in production?

Answer (score 0):

After spending a few more hours messing around with the code I found the problem and solution myself.

One of my included modules clashes with PaperTrail (it has callbacks).

I moved `has_paper_trail` to be first in the class declaration (before my modules) and the tests all started passing again.

Comment: Nice find.  The way papertrail adds callbacks can be confusing.  I'd like the registration of callbacks to be more explicit in future versions.